How to update a PowerApps table column?
I've created a new column in a PowerApps table:

The problem, is that it appears blank:

The problem with this, is that blank means null:

And I don't really want nulls, I want true or false.
How can I bulk update all records in the table so that column appears as false instead of null?

This is the standard behavior, when you create a new column the already created records have the value set as null instead of the default value.
You will need to update all the prior records, you can do with several tools but depends on how many records you have.
The important part is the filter, for example with C# code under 5000 records will be
QueryExpression queryRecords = new QueryExpression("tablename");
queryRecords.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false);
queryRecords.Conditions.AddCondition("newfield", ConditionOperator.Null);
EntityCollection collRecords = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryRecords);
foreach(Entity record in collRecords.Entities) {
    Entity updateRecord = new Entity(record.LogicalName, record.Id);
    updateRecord["newfield"] = false;
    service.Update(updateRecord);
}

this is just an example, it will be a bit slow and works for up to 5000 records, but it can give you an idea on how to implement the logic in other tools.

I would recommend using XrmToolbox and SQL4CDS plugin. You can write and run the query similar to native SQL:
Update <tablename>
Set <newfield> = 0
Where createdon is not null//This is a stub - for some reason it barks if there are no conditions

